# Почему мой парсинг не работает? Я так понимаю, проблема в параметрах

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests

Ссылка откуда нужно парсить: https://investfunds.ru/funds/5629/

Мне нужно получать цену каждого дня в определенном промежутке. Вот мой код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я получаю на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1262879/edit))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотреть, чего запрашивает сама страничка с сайта, то вот это:

```
https://investfunds.ru/funds/5629/?action=chartData&data_key=close&date_from=01.03.2021&date_to=28.03.2021&currencyId=1&ids%5B%5D=5629
```

Просто указывайте все параметры, включая `currencyId` и `ids[]`. Если что, `%5B` и `%5D` - это url-encoded `[` и `]` соответственно.

```
import requests

url = 'https://investfunds.ru/funds/5629/'
date_from = '12.11.2020' 
date_to = '26.03.2021'

payload = {
  'action': 'chartData',
  'data_key': 'close',
  'date_from': date_from,
  'date_to':date_to,  
  'ids[]': 5629,
  'currencyId':1
}

r = requests.get(url, payload)

print(r.text) # [{"data":[[1605128400000,875.11000000000001],[160521480...
```